# jquery validation generate label .error outside the label

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form and each input text is contained within a label. How I can do to make the label that is generated by jquery validation (.error),appears outside of the input text label ?. I would get the error message below the text field.

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Please complete form</legend>
    <p>
        <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)
        <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required />
  </label>
    <p>
        <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)
        <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required />
  </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="curl">URL (optional)
        <input id="curl" type="url" name="url" />
  </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)
        <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
  </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]
   http://jsfiddle.net/qh7cqhpn/

I need that when .error class is generated, appears outside the label of the input text. I would like to know an effective way to do this. I can have 30 fields on a form, then there would like to field by field modification.
Thank you.

Comment: Please review the documented options:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement) (default `label`) into `div` and it will automatically wrap to the next line.  Otherwise, you can change the error element into anything you wish or leave it as a `label`.

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    errorElement: 'div'
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/qh7cqhpn/1/**

If you want to place the `.error` element outside of the existing `label` in your structure, then you would use the `errorPlacement` function.  `.insertAfter(element.parent())` will place it after the parent (`label`) of the input element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#commentForm").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/qh7cqhpn/2/**

Comment: can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368263/red-edge-mark-to-the-label-that-contains-the-item-to-validate-jquery-validation